# I want to manipulate the group file entries

Tags: text-processing

Suppose I have a file:

```
uid=1(a) groups=cat,dog,hen
uid=2(b) groups=cat,hen
uid=3(c) groups=hen
uid=4(d) groups=dog,hen,buffalo,horse
```

I am looking for:

```
cat a,b
dog a,d
hen a,b,c,d
buffalo d
horse d
```

List #1: Users & Secondary groups (for each user)

List #2: Groups & Users (belonging to the group)

Comment: What tools are available? What have you tried?

Comment: awk, perl, python are available. I have been trying transposing rows to columns (for groups string), not finding the appropriate algo to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F "[= ,()]" '{
    for(i=6;i<=NF;i++){
        if(a[$i] != ""){
            a[$i]=a[$i]","$3
        }else{
            a[$i]=$3
        }
    }
}
END{
    for ( i in a){
        print i,a[i]
    }
}'
```

create array with indexes as each group member and add append `uid` to this array when the group member is found on a line. 
at the `END` prin the array index as well the value in array.

Comment: there can be 20+ groupnames here
group=
why we are hardcoding 6?

Comment: 6 is the field number where the we start checking the group member in a line. Try `awk -F "[= ,()]" '{print $6}'`. The first for loop will run from 6th filed till last field `NF` and create array with index as this members.

Comment: Suppose if you have 20 members loop will be from 6th field to 26(20+6)th field ie `NF`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my %groups;

while ( my $line = readline *STDIN ) {
  chomp $line;
  if ( $line =~ m/\((?<user>[^)]+)\) groups=(?<groups>.+)/ ) {
    for my $groupname ( split ',', $+{groups} ) {
      push @{ $groups{$groupname} }, $+{user};
    }
  } else {
    warn "NOTICE non-matching line $. - '$line'\n";
  }
}

for my $groupname ( sort keys %groups ) {
  say $groupname, ' ', join ',', @{ $groups{$groupname} };
}
```

This version uses a hash (groups) of array refs (the users) and warns if it cannot match an input line (is your data corrupt? how would you know?).

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne '
  if (/^uid=\d+\((.+)\) groups=(.*)/) {
    push @{$u{$_}}, $1 for split /,/, $2;
  }
  END {
    $" = ",";
    print "$_ @{$u{$_}}" for keys %u;
  }'
```